# Laravel query not giving desired result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Can someone help fix this query.  Query is returning null result for "j.code" and "accounts.title".  And I am 100% sure that it should return result.  I think my left join are missing something.  Is this the proper way of using left join within a left join.

```
$query = DB::table('autostk')
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where('autostk.itemcode',$request->itemcode)
    ->whereDate('autostk.date','<=',$request->tdate)
    ->leftjoin('journal AS j', function($join) use ($branch_id) {
        $join->on('autostk.refno', '=', 'j.vno')
            ->where('j.code', '>=', 100)
            ->where('j.branchid', $branch_id)
            ->where('j.vtype', '=', 'autostk.vtype')
            ->leftjoin('accounts', 'j.code', '=', 'accounts.code')
            ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id);
    })
    ->select('j.code','accounts.title','autostk.*')
    ->orderBY('date')->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array) $item;
    })
    ->all();
```

The raw query being generated is :

```
select `j`.`code`, `accounts`.`title`, `autostk`.* from `autostk`
left join (`journal` as `j` left join `accounts` on `j`.`code`=`accounts`.`code`)
on `autostk`.`refno` = `j`.`vno` and `j`.`code` >= ? and `j`.`branchid` = ?
and `j`.`vtype` = ? and `accounts`.`branchid` = ? where `autostk`.`branchid` = ?
and `autostk`.`itemcode` = ? and date(`autostk`.`date`) <= ? order by
`autostk`.`date` asc
```

UPDATE : 
While checking the QueryLog i noticed that the binding for 'j'.'vtype' is "autostk.vtype"
Applying the query in workbench with 'autostk.vtype' returned null results.
But when I changed it to 'autostk'.'vtype' the results showed up correctly.
How to make this change in Laravel Eloquent ?

Comment: It would be easier if you try first to debug your query using the `toSql()` function.

Comment: Why are you doing a left join if you're sure the columns should always contain results?

Comment: I have updated my post with the raw query.

Answer (score 0):

```
->leftjoin('journal as j', function($join) use ($branch_id) {
```

`as` instead of `AS`

Comment: Result is still the same.  null values returned.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below:

```
$query = DB::table('autostk')
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where('autostk.itemcode',$request->itemcode)
    ->whereDate('autostk.date','<=',$request->tdate)
    ->leftjoin('journal as j', function($join) use ($branch_id) {
        $join->on('autostk.refno', '=', 'j.vno')
            ->where('j.code', '>=', 100)
            ->where('j.branchid', $branch_id)
            ->where('j.vtype', '=', 'autostk.vtype')
            ->leftjoin('accounts', 'j.code', '=', 'accounts.code')
            ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id);
    })
    ->select('j.code','accounts.title','autostk.*')
    ->orderBy('autostk.date')->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array) $item;
    })
    ->all();
```

There is one problem:

```
->orderBy('autostk.date')
```

And you can use toArray() instead of map() like this

```
->orderBy('autostk.date')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Updating autostk.date did not fix the problem j.code and accounts.title are still null.  I have included the raw query in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  Correct query is :

```
$query = DB::table('autostk')
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where('autostk.itemcode',$request->itemcode)
    ->whereDate('autostk.date','<=',$request->tdate)
    ->leftjoin('journal AS j', function($join) use ($branch_id) {
        $join->on('autostk.refno', '=', 'j.vno')
        ->on('autostk.vtype', '=', 'j.vtype')
            ->where('j.code', '>=', 100)
            ->where('j.branchid', $branch_id)
            ->leftjoin('accounts', 'j.code', '=', 'accounts.code')
            ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id);
    })
    ->select('j.code','accounts.title','autostk.*')
    ->orderBY('autostk.date')->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array) $item;
    })
    ->all();
```